# How do I make Tomcat7 a user that owns a folder without apt-get?

Tags: spring, tomcat7, ubuntu-14.04, apt, file-ownership

Backstory: I'm using tomcat7 to host Java Spring code for an API with Ionic but we discovered that file:// gets blocked by tomcat7 service and Ionic sends an origin of file://. This is a bug that was fixed in 7.0.71. Apt-Get Install tomcat7 only installs tomcat7=7.0.52 on Ubuntu 14.04 so I had to manually install 7.0.71 through a zip file in /opt/tomcat7 folder using the instructions here:
http://tecadmin.net/install-tomcat-7-on-ubuntu/#

So now that you know why I don't have a user in /etc/default, I need tomcat7 to own a folder since I only want tomcat7 to have the permissions to store to that folder. How do I make this happen?

Comment: with [chown](https://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/chown/) on the server

Comment: I tried chown but it tells me there is no user "tomcat7". Unless you mean chown on apache/nginx kind of thing?

Comment: Then you have to create the user wit [adduser](https://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/adduser/). You can create the user as system user which is the better choice for users running a service